# How do I work with both strings and integers from a file?

Tags: python

I have a text file with names, what grade the student is in, and the scores the students received on a test.  It is in this format:

```
John Doe 3 87
Jane Doe 4 89
Bob Smith 5 84
```

I need to find the average of all the students in the 3rd, 4th, and 5th grade.  This is what I've done:

```
    inFile = open("input.txt", "r", encoding = "utf8")
    counter5 = 0
    counter4 = 0
    counter3 = 0
    total5 = 0
    total4 = 0
    total3 = 0
    for line in inFile:
        if "5" in line:
            total5 += int(line[-3:-1])
            counter5 += 1
        elif "4" in line:
            total4 += int(line[-3:-1])
            counter4 += 1
        elif "3" in line:
            total3 += int(line[-3:-1])
            counter3 += 1
    print(total5/counter5)
    print(total4/counter4)
    print(total3/counter3)
```

The problem, of course, is that in my if statements, it's possible that a "3", "4", or "5" appears in the test score and not only as the grade level. I'm sure there are way simpler ways of doing this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you're reading tabular data, you should use `pandas` or at the very least `csv.reader`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's just a text file with row after row of name, grade, score

Comment: you could use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) to extract grades and scores from the lines.

Comment: Use `int(line.split()[-2])` for the grade and `int(line.split()[-1])` for the scores?

Comment: If you don't want guesses and hit and miss type suggestions. it is advisable to share ALL the information, so that people here can RECREATE your your scenario.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This helps in saving a lot ..a lot of time. Advisable to show what the text file looks like.

Comment: _Unfortunately, it's just a text file_. Pandas works perfectly fine with text files, btw

Answer (score 1):

As was recommended, this can be done using pandas.

Here's how to solve for this using pandas.

Input file (input.txt):

```
John Doe 3 87
Jane Doe 4 89
Bob Smith 5 84
Chris Cruse5 3 85
Karen Cane4 4 93
Rob Green3 5 94
Babe Ruth4 3 78
Step Curry1 4 79
Leb James4 5 77

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = ['First','Last','Grade','Score']
print (df)
print (df.groupby('Grade')['Score'].mean().round(2))
```

The data will be stored into the pandas dataframe as:

```
   First    Last  Grade  Score
0   John     Doe      3     87
1   Jane     Doe      4     89
2    Bob   Smith      5     84
3  Chris  Cruse5      3     85
4  Karen   Cane4      4     93
5    Rob  Green3      5     94
6   Babe   Ruth4      3     78
7   Step  Curry1      4     79
8    Leb  James4      5     77
```

The Mean value of each grade will be:

```
Grade
3    83.33
4    87.00
5    85.00
```

You can also give:

```
print (df.groupby('Grade').agg({'Score':['mean']}).round(2))

       Score
        mean
Grade       
3      83.33
4      87.00
5      85.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the line into tokens:

```
>>> line = 'Jane Doe 3 87'
>>> line.split(' ')
['Jane', 'Doe', '3', '87']
```

Note that this are strings, you need to cast them for your purpose:

```
>>> float(line.split(' ')[-1])
87
```

More complete version:

```
inFile = open("input.txt", "r", encoding = "utf8")
    counter5 = 0
    counter4 = 0
    counter3 = 0
    total5 = 0
    total4 = 0
    total3 = 0
    for line in inFile:
        score = float(line.split(' ')[-1])
        grade = int(line.split(' ')[-2])
        if 5 == grade:
            total5 += score
            counter5 += 1
        elif 4 == grade:
            total4 += score
            counter4 += 1
        elif 3 == grade:
            total3 += score
            counter3 += 1
    print(total5/counter5)
    print(total4/counter4)
    print(total3/counter3)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find the average of all the students in the 3rd, 4th, and 5th grade

Collect the grade and the scores into a dict, loop over it and calculate the stats

See below

```
from collections import defaultdict
import statistics

data = defaultdict(list)
with open('in.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        fields = line.split()
        fields[-1] = int(fields[-1])
        data[fields[2]].append(fields[-1])
for grade, scores in data.items():
    print(f'{grade} --> {statistics.mean(scores)}')
```

in.txt

```
John Doe 3 87
Jane Doe 4 89
Bob Smith 5 84
John Doe12 3 88
Jane Doe12 4 90
Bob Smith12 5 85
```

output

```
3 --> 87.5
4 --> 89.5
5 --> 84.5
```